# iOS play background video in a view

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, ios5, playback

I've added this code to the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"myvid" ofType:@"m4v"];
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    MPMoviePlayerController* moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view insertSubview: moviePlayer.view aboveSubview: self.view];
    [moviePlayer play];
```

it doesn't work! how can I play a video in the background of a view in iOS? (using storyboards)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the instance of MPMoviePlayerController you create is wounded by ARC during the playback.

Try making the strong property of MPMoviePlayerController and assign the instance you create there before starting playback.

So your code will look like this

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"myvid" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
//set the frame of movie player
self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
[self.view addSubView:self.moviePlayer.view];
[self.moviePlayer play];
```